# Corona SDK and Evernote

Tags: ios, coronasdk, evernote

What is the best approach to access Evernote API using Corona SDK. I've just started to use Corona (I'm a Lua noob) but Evernote don't have a sdk yet for this platform...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible unless Corona officially support this.

Answer (score 0):

Use free native development option to develop your native plugin for iOS.

Comment: This seems to be more like a comment. Edit your answer by elaborating more.